# How to send status to web worker in order that we may cancel and return an error without waiting response (onmessage)

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Web worker allows methods: PostMessage and Terminate, not provide something that we can notify status (like cancellation for long-running query) to web worker and return an error (cancel) immediately.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker

If we use Terminate() to kill the worker, all loaded data will have to load again when a new worker is created. That is not good.

It looks like that it's hard to notify to webwork and return errors instead of killing the worker.

If you have a solution, please give me your advice.